# How can I pass values from an array to the constructor? C++

Tags: c++, arrays, constructor

I've created a program that reads in data from a file and creates objects from them. However their values can vary and thus I made an array that can expand to a definite amount. When I try to pass said through the constructor I run into some trouble. Also I'm not supposed to use vectors which from what I understand would have made this a lot easier.

```
                    //bunch of code to read in data from the file similar to this below
        getline (readfile, typea);

                    //code determining what each data type is.          

readMedia >>NSA_Value;
for (int i=0; i<=NSA_Value; i++){
getline(readMedia, supporting_actorsa[i]); //this is the array I'm using that can grow a bit to accommodate.

Vhs initial = Vhs(typea, a, b, c, supporting_actorsa[10]); //the constructor ive removed most of the other things to make it more readable.
```

This is the cpp file it calls on create the object

```
#include "Vhs.cpp"


Vhs::Vhs (string type, string a1, string b1, string c1, supporting_actorsa1[10])
{
}
Vhs::Vhs(void)
{
}


Vhs::~Vhs(void)
{
}
```

and this it it's .h file

```
#pragma once
class Vhs
{

public:

    Vhs(void);
    Vhs (string type, string A2, string B2, string C3, string supporting_actorsA3[10]);
~Vhs(void);


};
```

all the variables exist, i just removed all the declarations to make things look cleaner.
Thanks for any help

Comment: *"When I try to pass said through the constructor I run into some trouble"* - Define "trouble".  Details matter.

Comment: Why can't you use vectors? That would make this entire situation trivial :)

Comment: There's a question there, somewhere, I know it is, but alas it eludes my grasp.

Comment: Sorry! when I try to run my program it would either tell me there is no Constructor instance of Vhs in the way i wrote it or that it was of the wrong type. Im editing it again right now based on someone said below. and Ill try and make my problem clearer after that if it still doesnt work

Comment: "all the variables exist, i just removed all the declarations to make things look cleaner." No, actually, code that doesn't include details does not make things cleaner.  You should realize you do not know what is important or not.  Create a self contained small example that demonstrates your problem -- remove parts that aren't required to show your problem, but leave in EVERYTHING that is required to make your program compile. You should be able to copy-paste it to ideone.com and get it to compile (or fail in exactly the way that you are puzzled about). I'd bet you have other problems.

Comment: Sorry about that, I didn't want to make it seem like I intended for the community to do the problem for me. I will do this next time. for now though I've sorted my initial problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass a C-array like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
class Vhs {
public:
    Vhs (string type, string A2, string B2, string C3, 
         string *supporting_actorsA3, int n); 
};  
Vhs::Vhs (string type, string a1, string b1, string c1, 
          string *supporting_actorsa1, int n) {
  for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    cout << supporting_actorsa1[i] << endl;
  }
}

int main()
{
  string supporting_actorsa[1024];
  int num_actors;
  num_actors = 2;
  supporting_actorsa[0] = "1";
  supporting_actorsa[1] = "2";
  Vhs initial = Vhs("typea", "a", "b", "c", supporting_actorsa, 
      num_actors);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks i'll give this a go a see if I run into anymore problems. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: I thought when he said he couldn't use vectors he meant he couldn't use them at all, not just for his constructor. Vectors would definitely make it easier though.

Comment: yeah I can't use vectors at all :/ I left out the vector stuff and it compiled, but I'm not if sure that means I'll be running into problems later on.

Comment: Oy thanks a lot! I found a work around by scanning everything into a string variable and appending it. It's not a good idea I know, but I do not need to edit them separately so it should be ok. Thanks again.